# Changes to SQLite are lost after connection.Close()

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Working with MonoTouch .NET for iPhone and SQLite on Mac OSX. I can read from the database no problem. However, when I attempt to make changes to the database, I get strange behavior. The code below runs without exception, but no real changes are being made to the database. I can create a table, insert a record, select that record, and display it in the console. But, when I close the db connection, all those changes go away. Further, if I put a break-point in the code before conn.Close() and check the database, the table doesn't exist. Sounds like I'm only working with an imaginary database that responds to actual SQL statements. Weird.

This code runs but does not actually write anything to the database:

```
const string _connectionString = "Data Source=App_Data/MyDatabaseFile";

var conn = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();

var command = conn.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Test (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, text varchar(100))";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

var cmd2 = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Test (Text) Values ('test test test')";
var rowsAffected = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); //rowsAffected is 1

var cmd3 = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Test";
var reader = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
Console.WriteLine(reader["text"]); //writes "test test test" to console, nothing in database

conn.Close();
```

If I execute the same SQL statements in in SQLite Browser, they work fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, text varchar(100));
INSERT INTO Test (Text) Values ('test test test');
SELECT * FROM Test;
```

... yields { id = 1, text = 'test test test' }

You can probably tell, but it's worth mentioning that I'm not using transactions.

UPDATE:

Interesting... I can change the code above that runs the SELECT query to look in 'Test2' (non-existent table) and it throws an SQLiteException: "No such table: Test2".

I also tried wrapping the above code in a transaction on the off chance that SQLite requires transactions... no dice.

UPDATE #2:

Adam suggested trying to open a new connection and SELECT from the new table again before stopping the application. I added the following code after the above code:

```
var conn2 = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
conn2.Open();
var cmd4 = conn2.CreateCommand();
cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Test";
var reader2 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
Console.WriteLine("2nd attempt: " + reader2["text"]); //outputs correctly
conn.Close();
```

Alright, so my assumption about it losing changes after connection.Close() is incorrect. It definitely found the newly inserted row and output it to the console. However, the table and row still disappear after I stop the application.

Comment: Is this inside a device emulator?  Instead of looking at the database, can you try creating a code command to select out what you've just inserted?

Comment: Yes. I'm using monoDevelop and the iPhone simulator. I've been looking at the database, but the code above also tries to select what's been inserted.

Comment: So it does... didn't spot that.

Comment: Funny thing is, it DOES select what's been inserted. But once the connection is closed, all that disappears. I'm new to monotouch and sqlite, so I'm sure there's something easy I'm missing.

Comment: When you are running the emulator, can you confirm its using the same database as the one you are checking afterwards?  Also, can you close the connection and then programmatically select out afterwards?

Comment: According to this post, at the very bottom, inserts into a SQLite db on an emulator don't work? http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=317

Comment: I am using the same database in both instances, unless monotouch is copying the database in my solution to another location to run with the emulator. I tried your suggestion and updated my question with the results. As for that blog post... hmmm... I sure hope it's incorrect or there's a work-around. Not being able to test a data-driven iphone app would be pretty crappy.

Comment: I've not got any experience with this either, but its sounding like the emulator is creating a copy on the fly for the duration of the emulation - which would explain why it doesn't persist and why you might not see any records (ie, you are looking at the wrong file). It could be caching this temp database somewhere. I'd post this information onto the MonoTouch forums too.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone dealing with the same question, I thought I'd go ahead and post my findings. The behavior I described in my original post is mostly by design. To be more clear, here's a better explanation:

When MonoDevelop deploys your app to the iPhone Simulator, a COPY of your SQLite database goes with it to live in the iPhone environment. So, when your app modifies your database, the original database isn't being touched. When your app stops, the changes you made to the simulator copy of your database are lost. However, while the app is running, you can insert, update, delete and select all you want and everything should work as expected.

This is only true when using the Simulator.